# full rankness of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I am given that $K=[B\hspace{0.5cm}AB\hspace{0.5cm}A^2B\dots\dots A^{n-1}B]$ is full rank $n$ where $A$ is a column stochastic and $B$ is a positive matrix. Now I define $M=(1-m)A+\frac{m}{n}P$, where $P$ is a matrix having all entries $1$, $m\in(0,1)$. Now could anyone help me to say anthing about rank of this new matrix

$L=[B\hspace{0.5cm}MB\hspace{0.5cm}M^2B\dots\dots M^{n-1}B]$?

$A,B$ matrices are of order $n$, $M$ is also column stochastic.

Comment: What is a column stochastic? And the positivity of $B$ means the entries are positive? (Otherwise, I would expect the term positive *definite*.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Column stochastic means each column sums to 1 and yes positive means entries are positive